# ionic2: ionic cordova run android error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have android SDK installed in:

```
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
```

and I enter this lines in the terminal:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and If I enter in the terminal before closing the terminal

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

I got the correct path, but if I close the terminal and open it again then enter the same line I have empty line which means that the path doesn't saved ,
and If I run may ionic project in android I have this error:

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Comment: you need to add the `export` lines to `.bash_profile` file not the terminal

Comment: @suraj that's what I do and echo $ANDROID_HOME print the correct path but ionic cordova run android print the same error that Android SDK not found

Comment: @suraj also,, the bash_profile was empty and when I add the lines on it I had error in visual studio code